# Logback-classic Appender for Microsoft Event Viewer

Tags: java, slf4j, logback-classic

We have an application written in Java and logging to logback-classic with slf4j. One of our customers has requested to also log to Windows Event Viewer. So, what I am looking for is an Appender for logback-classic that works with Microsoft Event Viewer. I thought these would be fairly simple to find, but it is not. The only thing I have found so far is a [log4j2 Appender](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47431378/windows-event-logging-with-log4j2-configuration-for-32-and-64-bit-windows). We could use log4j2 with slf4j, but log4j2 has security issues as far as I know. If you know of a logback-classic Appender or an other way to get our logging into Microsoft Event Viewer, please let me know.